# MYSQL move tables to second database and filter

Tags: mysql

I am trying to move tables from one database to another.  I am filtering the data during the process.  For instance:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS target_db.products;
CREATE TABLE target_db.products LIKE original_db.products;
INSERT INTO target_db.products 
    SELECT * FROM original_db.products 
    WHERE products_status = 1 
        AND products_date_added > (SELECT DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 18 MONTH));
```

This works fine and I get the records I expect.  But when the WHERE phrase includes another table it fails (because the column list does not match.) For example:

```
# export products
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS target_db.products_description;
CREATE TABLE target_db.products_description LIKE original_db.products_description;
INSERT INTO target_db.products_description 
    SELECT * FROM original_db.products_description pd,  original_db.products p  
    WHERE p.products_status = 1 
        AND p.products_date_added > (SELECT DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 18 MONTH)) 
        AND pd.products_id = p.products_id;
```

Is there a way around this other than overly specifying the columns?

Comment: I would specify the columns regardless. Otherwise MySQL might match them up incorrectly. Big mess.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,

Stupid question.  You use better structure of joins or a nested query.

Duh!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have * in your select the columns of the joins will be part of the result set. Specify them.

Comment: yes,  thanks.  exactly what i worked out.  but actually, practically on very large tables it was actually quicker to copy the table and delete the records that one did not want.  Then export that table.